# Why are some edits automatically rejected?

Tags: support, editing

Recently I tried to edit two questions, [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301933/boundary-conditions-in-poissons-equation-for-gravity) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302477/confusion-regarding-this-question). Both my edits were rejected by Community$\diamondsuit$, which I take as "automatically rejected", because they conflicted with a subsequent edit. Both edits were simply formal: I edited math formulas to make it cleaner and more understandable.

Now, I see that the second question has been put on hold so maybe this is the reason behind my edit not being accepted (but, is it?); for the first one I can not think of a reason not to accept my edit; subsequent edits by moderators fixed the spelling but, in my opinion, did not make the post more readable by including LaTeX rendering.

Since my edits were automatically rejected, what can be the reason of such a rejection? In particular, when there is conflict with a subsequent edit, which one is going to win? Is it reputation based, or decided by moderators, or what else?

Please note that this post is by no means polemic, I think that there is something I am missing about edit & review procedure so I would like to understand it in order to edit appropriately in the future.

---

**EDIT**

Review links:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157565
https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157926

Comment: As for the second post, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157926 (which confirms that the edit conflicted with a subsequent edit). When there are simultaneous edits, I think that the most significative one has priority (or whichever clicks on "save edit" first).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform but what defines the most significative one? Is putting a question "on hold" considered a (more significative) edit? Otherwise, what is the more significative edit you are talking about in this specific question?

Comment: I truly don't know. That's up to the algorithms of SE. In any case, I hope that this incident doesn't discourage you from editing post in the future. Editing posts to improve their quality is always a good thing.

Comment: @tomph Putting a question on hold is not an edit at all, and I don't believe it has any hearing on what happens to pending edits. That is, putting a question on hold cannot cause an edit to be rejected.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, I realized that after Emilio's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On both [this edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157926) and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157565), the edit was rejected because a user with full editing privileges (i.e. 2k+ reputation) started editing before you submitted your edit, as detailed [on this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits):

> #### A user with full edit privileges saves an edit over yours
>
> If a user with full editing privileges for a post (including the original poster) begins editing the post at the same time as you, and they save their edit after you have already suggested it, then your suggested edit will be overridden in favor of their fully-privileged edit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here is the review link for the other edit. I included it in the original post too, for completeness. http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157565